# How to Move the first word right after the second word

Tags: php

i have feeds from some site whose data is incosistence and the problem is that it is returning most of the data reverse.
So, i have author name:

say i am getting: `Shoemaker, Michael Myers`
But actually i want: `Michael Myers Shoemaker`

another example:
say i am getting: `Brainerd, Eleanor Hoyt` 
But actually i want: `Michael Myers Shoemaker`

another example:
say i am getting: `Gravengaard, N. P.` 
But actually i want: `N. P. Gravengaard`

Note: the author name is not necessary on 2 words, it may have 3 4 words as well so we cant rely on only first two keywords.

The code i am using:

```
$authname = explode(", ",$name);
$total = count($authname);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; ++$i) {
$result .= "  ".$authname[$i];
```

and i am getting: `Gravengaard N. P.`

Thank You.

hsz code best work for me. thank you hsz :)

Comment: Is this a mysql or php question?

Comment: it is PHP question mate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just try with:

```
$input  = 'Shoemaker, Michael Myers';
$output = implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(', ', $input)));

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string 'Michael Myers Shoemaker' (length=23)
```

Comment: Yes, much better than mine :)

Comment: Yup, also better than mine. :)

Comment: Here is result: `M` AND `M E` AND `M E B`

Comment: @user3714281 Sorry, I do not understand.

Comment: 100% perfect result. that is what i needed. BTW i made some mistake so i said this. :)

Comment: Thank You please. its great help for me.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one comma (,).. You can do something like this.

```
$name = "Poe, Edward Allan";
$authname = explode(", ",$name);
$name = $authname[1] . ' ' . $authname[0];
echo $name;
```

The result will be:

```
Edward Allan Poe
```

Comment: What if, the author name expands to 3 or 4 keywords? does this work mate?

Comment: @user3714281 You mean if the author name has 3 or words? This would still work fine.. Let say Original is name is `'Poe, Edward Allan'` --- The result will be `'Edward Allan Poe'`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code:

```
$authname = array_reverse(explode(", ",$name));
```

So your code will be

```
$authname = array_reverse(explode(", ",$name));
$total = count($authname);
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; ++$i) {
$result .= "  ".$authname[$i];
```

With `array_reverse` you basically reverse the order of your elements. Whe you "explode" returned string you'll obtain a string with same order but divided into `array` elements.

If you would like to know more on `array_reverse`, please consult this [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

#### Note

Of course your data need to be, everytime, in the same format or your result could be different respect what you expect
This solution is tailored to your example, [hsz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223386/hsz) one is much better :)

Comment: No luck. it adds other authors in the list as well. see: `Winged Wheels in France by Michael Myers Shoemaker` AND `Michael Myers Shoemaker Eleanor Hoyt Brainerd` AND `Michael Myers Shoemaker Eleanor Hoyt Brainerd B. L. (Benjamin Leopold) Farjeon`

Comment: Thank You please for the effort. you was saying right mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the following...

```
$authname = explode(", ",$name);
$total = count($authname);

// Place the first element at the back
$authname[] = array_shift($authname);
$result = implode(' ', $authname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
  $myvalue = 'Brainerd,Eleanor Hoyt ';
   $str="";
   $arr = explode(',',trim($myvalue));
   for($i=sizeof($arr);$i>=0;$i--){
   $str=$str.$arr[$i]." ";
   }
   echo $str;
 ?>
```

Hope this helps!